# Cannot connect to TS3 server after migration

Tags: teamspeak

I try to migrate a TS3 server from an UNIX server to another one, but after putting the **ts3server.sqlitedb** file, I cannot connect to my server.

I try to look at the DB, but there is nothing about IP or things like that. Ports are opened, and renaming or deleting this file makes the server great again.

I started looking on Google, people just say to copy the file, without any edit.

Do you have a idea ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

The problem was about the licence.

In the DB file, there are like 50+ rooms, so a licence is needed. Transferring as well the licence makes the server works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about the licence.

In the DB file, there are like 50+ rooms, so a licence is needed. Transferring as well the licence makes the server works just fine.